# How to link to texts inside para

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have the following two links in my main menu, and I have some texts in one page with different titles. When any one click on the first link I want to take my user directly to the first para that has heading -- "My title 1" and if any one clicks on the second link then I want to take my user directly to the second para that has heading -- "My title 2"

```
<a> Link to "My Title 1" </a>  ...Link 1   
<a> Link to "My Title 2" </a>   ...Link 2    


<h1> My Title 1 </h1>
  <p> My 500 line texts goes here </p>


<h1> My Title 2 </h1>
  <p> My 600 line texts goes here </p>
```

I have no idea how to achieve this, would you please kindly show me?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use what are called anchors. Apply an id to each heading and the same id to the `href`  property of the link. Make sure you prepend it with a hash (`#`). The browser will do the jumping for you.

```
<a href="#title1">Title 1</a>
<h1 id="title1">Title 1</h1>
```